# Self-study: Compute mean and std dev

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, normalization

Suppose that for a TV model it is known that 60% lasts more than 3 years, and 70% lasts less than 6 years. Assuming TV life follows a normal distribution. What is the mean and std dev?

These are the possible answers

```
a.   mean=3.677, std dev=3.561
b.  mean=3.977, std dev=3.861
c.   mean=4.177, std dev=3.561
d.  mean=4.377, std dev=3.261
e.  values cannot be computed
```

Can someone explain me how to resolve it? Will appreciate a lot

Comment: By drawing a reasonably faithful picture of a Normal curve and displaying where $3,$ the mean, and $6$ must belong, you can identify the mean accurately enough to answer the question.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and after some calculus arrived to option b).  Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't need any calculus!  I needed only to observe that 10% of the area under the curve lies between $3$ and the mean $\mu,$ 20% lies between $\mu$ and $6,$ and in this region the density is concave.  Thus $\mu$ must be a tiny bit *less* than $(0.10\times 6 + 0.20\times 3)/(0.10+0.20) = 4,$ and that gives option (b) as the only plausible answer. One could check this with a table of the standard Normal distribution function--which exam questions like this one almost always assume you have available and know how to use.